# huggingface pytorch-transformers: how to initialize embeddings with certain values?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am finetuning the bert model from [huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-transformers). Is there a way to manually set the initial embedding of a certain word piece? e.g. having the initial embedding of the word "dog" equal to `torch.ones(768)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set input embeddings of the BertModel: [get_input_embeddings()](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertModel.get_input_embeddings)

You need to know the word piece index from the vocabulary and can change the corresponding row in the embeddings matrix.